# ajax call returns null in my facebook iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, iframe

I am using jquery to send an ajax request from my facebook app which is in iframe to my server.
The ajax request works fine when the web app is running stand alone and out of facebook platform, but within facebook, the result that I get from my ajax request is blank !!!
Here is the code I use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://mydomain.com/search',
    data: params,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(posts) {
                // post is null !!!!!
             }
    error: function(json) {
                alert('error');
            }            
    });
```

I appreciate if anybody can help me with it.

Thanks.

uhsp

Answer (score -2):

Ok I solved it myself.
It was a cross domain issue.

Comment: how did you solve it? so future users can see the answer if they have the same question